# My website is not refreshing CSS changes made

Tags: caching, ip, hosting, cloudflare

I have one specific domain that this issue is connected with. I have 10+ more domains from the same registrar. This one domain is on a on a different webhosting account that the rest of the domains (the same webhosting company though).

Whenever I make changes to CSS, the changes are not reflected until I change an IP address via VPN. And even then, it only refreshes once, then I need to change the IP again to see another change made. Sometimes not even that helps.

This happens on different internet networks.

The website runs on wordpress, but I have tested it with a separate set of files outside of WordPress.

Does anyone have a clue what it may be and how could it be resolved? Thank you!

I have tried broadband, mobile network but it's the same scenario for both. This makes me believe that it's not a router or device issue (local cache). It goes without saying that I have cleared cache and DNS multiple times.

One thing to mention is that all of my domains run through Cloudflare - yet only one is affected.

My webhosting company is not very helpful this time and only have checked whether my IP is blocked, which I think is a useless taken the above scenario.

All of my other 10+ domains reflect the changes immediately, even without clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is experiencing something similar, it was due to Cloudflare. I have set the nameservers to point directly to the hosting provider and that fixed the issue.